# How to stub require('firebase-admin').auth().getUserByEmail() with sinon?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, sinon

Could you please share some example of Sinon stub for firebase-admin authentification. The challenge is to initialize firebase admin app for further stubs.

I tried the next code

```
  const admin = require('firebase-admin');
  sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');
  var noUserError = new Error('error');
  noUserError.code = 'auth/user-not-found';
  sinon.stub(admin, 'auth').returns({
    getUserByEmail: sinon.fake.rejects(noUserError)
  });
  var err = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);
  console.error(err);
```

but it returns

```
  Error (FirebaseAppError) {
    codePrefix: 'app',
    errorInfo: {
      code: 'app/no-app',
      message: 'The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.',
    },
    message: 'The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.',
  }
```

The expected result is exception Error with code = 'auth/user-not-found'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using firebase-mock helped.

https://github.com/soumak77/firebase-mock

```
  const firebasemock = require('firebase-mock');
  const mockauth = new firebasemock.MockAuthentication();
  const mockdatabase = new firebasemock.MockFirebase();
  const mocksdk = new firebasemock.MockFirebaseSdk(
    (path) => {
      return path ? mockdatabase.child(path) : mockdatabase;
    },
    () => {
      return mockauth;
    }
  );
  mocksdk.auth().autoFlush();

  proxyquire('../index', {
    'firebase-admin': mocksdk
  });
```

Answer (score 11):

Due to `admin.auth` being a getter, you can not stub it as a function but as a getter that returns a function with your stub object.
You need to use `stub.get(getterFn)` from Sinon API.

```js
sinon.stub(admin, 'auth').get(() => () => ({
  getUserByEmail: sinon.fake.rejects(noUserError)
}));
```